# String To Date Conversion in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column values like **20150921**. I want to convert this string value to a specified date format like **2015-09-21** in mysql.

Comment: Are you certain that the column value will always be in YYYYMMDD format?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
date_format(str_to_date('20150921', '%Y%m%d'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/21616)**

(*Assuming that you want your date format to be in YYYY-MM-DD format*)

Comment: Yes Its  Working. Thank you Rahul

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run this query on my MySql 5.6.

```
SELECT DATE('20150921');
```

So i believe, this should work directly `DATE(colStringDate)`

Comment: This will return the output as `September, 21 2015 00:00:00`

Comment: That depends on your system DateTime formatting. But the point is, you get a Date Type from an String.

Comment: Indeed but it is not recommended to rely on your system date and time setting as the query may fail when it moves to a different env. Also OP has specified the format in which s/he wants to see the result, so thats not a valid answer!

Comment: Yes, that correct. I oversaw that the output is needed in a definite format only.